# Assign Top frequent values in one column to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to find the 15 most frequent values in one column and assigning the to a new column.
I tried the below but it didn't work.

```
df2 = df.assign(job15 = df['job'].value_counts()[14::-1])
```

and this also

```
df['job15'] = df['job'].value_counts()[14::-1]
```

but they didn't work. Do any one have a way of doing it.
So the data set I am having now looks like this

```
Col0    Col1    Col2     job
11       02     ahn    Marketing
22       05     ghdf   Sales
58       058    syg    Sales
68       085    sdhj   Finance
86       088    sgx    Marketing
55       08     dyy    IT
```

And the result I want to have should look like this

```
Col0    Col1    Col2     job        job15
11       02     ahn    Marketing     Marketing
22       05     ghdf    Sales        Sales
58       058    syg     Sales        Sales
68       085    sdhj   Finance       Null
86       088    sgx    Marketing     Marketing
55       08     dyy      IT          Null
```

Answer (score 0):

try groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# sample data
dat = np.random.randint(0,20,size=1000).reshape((500,2))
df= pd.DataFrame(data=dat, columns=['A','countA'])

# aggregation with groupby on any "filled" column
aggr = df.groupby('A').count().sort_values(by='countA', ascending=False)

aggr = aggr.reset_index()

best15 = aggr[:15]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I clarified my question now and add an example